# Is this integral solvable? (Physics)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving a physics problem and I was solving it using a reference particle. During the solving , I came across this differential equation.

$$dx= \frac{GM}{x^2}(dt)^2$$
**G,M are constants.**

I haven't ever integrated such an equation. Is this integral solvable?

Comment: @KennyWong, the equation was $s=ut+\frac{at^2}{2}$, $u=0$, and $a=\frac{2GM}{x^2}$, and it covers distance $dx$ in $dt$

Comment: The equation $s = ut + \tfrac {at^2}{2}$ only applies to **constantly-accelerating** objects. Since your projectile is not constantly accelerating, this equation has no relevance whatsoever. Instead, you should solve $(d^2x / dt^2) = GM/x^2$ directly.

Comment: The first is free fall in a field of constant gravity, the second is the gravity field around a massive body. Both go only together of the motion is over distances that are small relative to the distance $x$ to the center of the massive body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean motion in a gravity field,
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{GM}{|x|^2}\hat x=-\frac{GMx}{|x|^3}.
$$
There are two ways to integrate once: Multiply with $2\dot x$ and get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}|\dot x|^2=\frac{GM}{|x|}+C
$$
and the cross product with $x$ to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\dot x\times x)=\ddot x\times x=0\implies \dot x\times x = D.
$$
These lead to the Kepler laws of planetary motion.